# display images in datagrid with Compact Framework

Tags: compact-framework, datagrid

is it possible to display an image in a datagrid cell? 
i'm currently working with compact framework 3.5.

any tips on that?

Answer (score 9):

Like the other posters have commented, you're required to roll your own. Luckily, this isn't too difficult.

In my application, I needed a way to draw a 16x16 icon in a particular column. I created a new class that inherits from `DataGridColumnStyle`, which makes it easy to apply to a `DataGrid` via a `DataGridTableStyle` object.

```
class DataGridIconColumn : DataGridColumnStyle {

public Icon ColumnIcon {
    get;
    set;
}

protected override void Paint( Graphics g, Rectangle bounds, CurrencyManager source, int rowNum, Brush backBrush, Brush foreBrush, bool alignToRight ) {

    // Fill in background color
    g.FillRectangle( backBrush, bounds );

    // Draw the appropriate icon
    if (this.ColumnIcon != null) {
        g.DrawIcon( this.ColumnIcon, bounds.X, bounds.Y );
    }
  }
}
```

You can see that I defined the public property `ColumnIcon` so I can specify the icon I need to display outside of this class.

Now, to actually use it on a DataGrid, you'd have a snippet like:

```
DataGridTableStyle ts = new DataGridTableStyle();

DataGridIconColumn dgic = new DataGridIconColumn();
dgic.ColumnIcon = Properties.Resources.MyIcon;
dgic.MappingName = "<your_column_name>";
dgic.HeaderText = "<your_column_header>";

ts.GridColumnStyles.Add(dgic);

this.myDataGrid.TableStyles.Add( ts );
```

That's a pretty simple example for applying the `DataGridTableStyle` -- I actually do a lot of further customization on the rest of my `DataGrid` columns. But it should get you started on what you want to do.

Comment: If i need to load a image in cell ?? How do i do it ?

Answer (score 1):

The only way that I know how to do this would be like the trick for rendering textboxes in the grid by using a trick to paint some images over the grid.

One of the [CF team posted something about customising the grid on their site.](http://blogs.msdn.com/netcfteam/archive/2006/04/25/583542.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

It's the same process as doing [multiline rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126196/net-compact-framework-can-you-get-grids-which-have-multi-line-text-in-cells), [changing row colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/408113/changing-row-colors-in-the-compact-framework-datagrid), [making the text right-to-left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872137/how-to-use-datagrid-in-right-to-left-like-hebrew-or-arabic-language), or [highlighting a row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/839268/windows-mobile-how-to-highlight-row-in-datagrid-and-compilation-delays): you have to [custom draw](http://blogs.msdn.com/netcfteam/archive/2006/04/25/583542.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to use a third-party solution, have a look at Resco [SmartGrid](http://www.resco.net/developer/mobileformstoolkit/smartgrid.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

http://www.cf-technologies.net/compactgrid.php. You can use cell's CustomDraw event..